# Conditionally set an attribute of input fields to required if a checkbox is selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, attributes, jquery-selectors, jquery-tools

I'm using the jquery Tools validator plugin and I have a form with several sections. Each section has a checkbox at the top that I want to be like a main switch for each section - to programatically turn on/off functionality (like validation) for text boxes & email fields in each section.

Basically, I wanted to conditionally set an attribute of 'text' and/or 'email' type input field(s) to "required" if the corresponding group checkbox is selected. Admittedly, I'm not that good with jQuery.

Each form section is similar to below but may have a different number of text and/or email fields:

```
<input type="checkbox" group-name="mail" name="mail" id="mail_enable"
       checked="<?= (chkConfig("mail_enable", 0) ? "yes" :  "no"); ?>"
       onChange="chkRequired('mail');"   
       title='check this box to send the specified reports to your email.' > 
       <label for="mail_enable">notify me when the batch is complete.</label></div>
  <div class="left"><label for="lblemailid">Email Address: </label></div>
  <div class="right"><input type="email" group-name="mail" name="mailto" 
       id="emailAddress" size="30" maxlength="50" />
```

I created an attribute called group-name and all of the fields in a section share the same group-name. and with the help of Mr. Frédéric Hamidi (in our discussion below) we have modified my function. here is the latest version:

```
  function chkRequired(group){ 
    var groupCheckBox = $("#" + group + "_enable");
    var groupSelector = "[group-name='" + groupCheckBox.attr("group-name") + "']";
    var fieldSelector = "input[type=text], input[type=email]";
     if  ( $(groupCheckBox).is(':checked'))  {
        $(groupSelector).add(fieldSelector).attr("required");
       } else { 
        $(groupSelector).add(fieldSelector).removeAttr("required");
     }
   }
```

I hope this helps anyone else in a similar situation.

I still cant figure out the selector syntax to attach it to the doc.ready() amd .change() globally. but it works if you assign the function to the onChange event for the fields, manually.

Also, if anyone can help me with the syntax for validator.addMethod() so we can just create a custom validation method - that would be appreciated.

Special thanks to Mr. Frédéric Hamidi for helping me work out the logic.

I've created a more detailed tutorial if anyone is interested @ http://www.logicwizards.net/2010/12/07/jquery-tools-custom-validator-mod/

Joe Negron: Logic Wizards ~ NYC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `$('#'+groupName).val()` returns `undefined` because your check box matches `#mail_enable`, not `#mail`. You don't even need to compute it a second time, since you used it the line before to get at the group name.

Also, [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns the *value* of the check box, not its check state. You need the [checked](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_checked.asp) attribute (or the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector) for that:

```
function chkRequired(group)
{
    var groupCheckBox = $("#" + group + "_enable");
    var groupSelector = "[group-name='" + groupCheckBox.attr("group-name") + "']";
    if (groupCheckBox.is(":checked")) {
        $("input:text" + groupSelector).attr("required", "required");
        $("input[type='mail']" + groupSelector).attr("required", "required");
    } else { 
        $("input:text" + groupSelector).removeAttr("required");
        $("input[type='mail']" + groupSelector).removeAttr("required");
    }
}
```

Comment: not quite there... groupCheckBox.checked doesn't ever seem to change... I've tried 'groupCheckBox.val()','groupCheckBox.attr("checked")!==null','groupCheckBox.checked', and '($(groupCheckBox+":checked").val())'

Comment: i did a 'alert( $(groupCheckBox).attr("selected")!==null ? "yay" : "nay");" right before 'if   ( $(groupCheckBox).attr("selected")!==null)  {' it always comes back true... am I not getting the jq selector or could it be a bug w/':selected'

Comment: @WWWIZARDS, maybe try calling `chkRequired()` from an `onclick` event handler instead of `onchange`?

Comment: the correct conditional is "($(groupCheckBox).is(':checked'))" - thanx for the help

Comment: @WWWIZARDS, yup, you're right, I forgot `groupCheckBox` was a jQuery object. You don't need to call `$()` again, though. Also `groupCheckBox.get(0).checked` will work too. I'll update my answer.

Comment: dayum! but it still wont set the required attribute - this sux!

Comment: `get(0)` returns the first DOM element in the jQuery object.

Comment: @WWWIZARDS, got it, we were missing a hyphen in the `group-name` attribute. Answer updated.

Comment: i can't post images yet but  - here's a screenshot... http://www.logicwizards.net/screenshot.png -- i don't know if it helps to get a visual? i think it has to do with groupSelector...

Comment: FYI: I put a -- $(function(){ $('input[type=checkbox][name|=enable]').change(function(){chkRequired(this.attr("group-name")); }); but that didn't wok so I manually put a -- onChange="chkRequired ('ftp');" -- onto each where ID=group+"_enable" OR name=group-name. that didn't fix it but sure made the broken parts show up in more places. :(
 
I thought it mighta had to do with "this" which was passed as reference to the event method that called the function - I thought I was onto something -- but, no luck there...

Comment: Did you try with `click()` instead of `change()`? :)

Comment: could we use a nested chain? something like: $(groupSelector).find("input[type=text]").find("input[type=email]") or similar and then set each "first" in the stack to what we want? or am I making it too complex?

Comment: That should work the same way as what we're already doing... Do the `group-name` selectors actually match something or does the problem occur when adding the `required` attributes?

Comment: yeah. they match the ID perfectly and even have the # in front of the string. it's probably something stupid like a comma or some other delimiter when we concatenate the selector...

Comment: sorry, I didn't imagine it was this f'kd up... I appreciate your sticktoitiveness. thanx. };-)

Comment: No problem :) Maybe the best would be to retry from scratch, proceeding step by step and validating that everything works in each step before tackling the next: first, get the checkbox state, next, find the input controls and finally, set them as required.

Comment: I'm too stubborn to start over. We're very close. The checkbox state is OK with (groupCheckBox.is(":checked")) -- the conditinal works. it's just not setting the attribute properly. That's the last piece of the puzzle. I was kinda hoping to use the validator API and create a custom rule but I think I'll still have the problem of setting the attribute. Maybe after I get some sleep, i'll see where that road leads... thanks again, sir.

Comment: I think I've got it! -- $(groupSelector).add("input[type=text], input[type=email]").attr("required", "required"); -- 1st we grab the group-selector stack and then "add" another selector with commas to make it a logical "OR" so in my mind its kinda an "if A and (B or C) then {change-attributes}" -- does that make sense?

Comment: Yup, that should work. Note that you can use `input:text` instead of `input[type=text]` to make that shorter. Also, I think `email` should be wrapped in single quotes, but I can't guarantee it :)

Comment: It works after a few slight mods and I updated the original post. Thank you again for helping me to understand everything...